# How to read from input and report whether two strings have exactly the same 'tokens' at the exact same positions?

Tags: java, boolean, token

Im trying to basically report whether or not string1 and string2 contain exactly the same tokens in the same order. I can't find whats wrong with my code. I fixed the infinite loop but now it doesn't check an empty string.

```
public static boolean sameTokens (String s1, String s2)
{
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(s1);
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(s2);

    boolean contains = true;

    String token1 = scan1.next();
    String token2 = scan2.next();




        while (token1.length() <= token2.length())
        {
            if (!(scan1.hasNext() || scan2.hasNext()))
            {
                contains = false;
            }
            if (token1.equals(token2))
            {
                contains = true;
            }

    }

    return contains;

}
```

These are my test cases.

```
  @Test
public void testSameTokens ()
{
    assertTrue(sameTokens("this is a test", " this  is  a  test "));
    assertTrue(sameTokens("", ""));
    assertFalse(sameTokens("hello there", "hello there Joe"));
    assertFalse(sameTokens("abc def", "def abc"));
    assertFalse(sameTokens("a", "A"));
    assertFalse(sameTokens("a b c", "abc"));
}
```

And this is the result.

[image: Result of Test case 1]

[image: Image of error]

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: How can you have fixed the infinite loop, when you don't actually change any of the values used in the loop condition inside the loop?

Comment: Any clue as to what I should change it to?

Comment: You start by editing the question and show the actual code you have. You know, the code where you supposedly fixed the infinite loop. I don't even understand the purpose of the loop, *as currently shown*, since you already set `contains = false;` right before the loop, and the only effect the loop can have is to do it again, so why even have the loop?

Comment: Hows that? I don't know how to do what is asked in the question basically. The for loop is what my code is right now and it doesn't work.

Comment: Since your code is not even close to do what your assignment is asking, and you surely haven't even "fixed the infinite loop", you are basically asking us to write the code for you. Sorry, that's not what this site is for.

Comment: Wait, did I ask for answers? No I didnt, I asked for someone to explain how I would go about doing this. The steps in order to achieve what the assignment is asking.

Comment: *Hint 1:* What is the point of comparing the length of the token text? Don't --- *Hint 2:* If your code is supposed to compare all tokens of the input, don't you think you need to call `next()` as part of the loop, in order to get all the tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code and it outputs the expected true values.

```
public static boolean sameTokens(String s1, String s2) {

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(s1);
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(s2);

    while(scan1.hasNext()||scan2.hasNext()){
        if ((!scan1.hasNext() && scan2.hasNext()) || (!scan2.hasNext() && scan1.hasNext())) {
            return false;
        } else {
            String token1 = scan1.next();
            String token2 = scan2.next();

            if (!token1.equals(token2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what I was doing wrong. I wasn't taking in account what would happen when the strings didn't match. hello world and hello world Joe for example.

Comment: Posting ready-to-use code without any explanation, especially if it is homework, is not a good answer. For homework, the answer should contain some hints, maybe pseudo-code and a lot more explanation.